# Parsing a command line variable as data frame column

Tags: r

I am trying to run a R script file from command line. My code on the command line is as below:

```
Rscript command_test.R name_of-data_frame col_name
```

In my R script file, command_test.R, code is as below:

```
library(dplyr)
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)


grpd_by_variable<-args[1]%>%
  group_by(args[2])%>%
  mutate(TOTAL=n())%>%
  filter(row_number()==1)

grpd_by_variable
```

I would want to pass both the data frame name i.e. args[1] and as well as column from the data frame i.e. args[2] from the command line. However, when I run this script, I am seeing the following error.

```
Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"
Calls: %>% ... _fseq -> freduce -> <Anonymous> -> group_by -> group_by_
Execution halted
```

Any idea on how to work around this issue please? Seems like R is interpreting the command line parameter as string and hence the issue.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: group_by(as.character(args[2]))%>%   may do

Comment: @user3142384 I tried that option. It didnt work. I even tried as.factor as well, without any luck.

Comment: Actually the issue seems to be with args[1] which is the data frame I want to refer to. I want to pass the data frame name as a command line argument. However, it doesn't seem to work this way. when I execute print(colnames(args[1])), it prints NULL. I even tried as.data.frame(args[1]), but without any luck

Comment: How about using `get(dfname)`? That is the standard R function for using a character value to retrieve a named object.

Comment: @42- Thanks get(dfname) worked. However, when I tried to do the same with data frame columns, it doesnt work. Effectively, what I want is to load the data frame, group_by on a particular column which is again passed as a command line parameter. I tried with get, as.character, as.name and using args[2] directly for the group_by clause. But its not working. Any pointers please?

Comment: I _think_ it will "work" but since you posted no code or error message, I cannot tell what error you're making, and since this is being done in the 'hadleyverse', I cannot really be sure whether my base-R theories will always be effective. Post a reproducible question. I'm not inclined toward building test cases. It's your responsibility.

Comment: It worked when I substituted group_by with group_by_ [In my other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802761/working-with-r-command-line-parameters-data-frame-columns/33803642#33803642) @zx8754 provided me with a solution which resolved this. Thanks for your help and support.