# Working with R Command Line Parameters - Data frame columns

Tags: r

I am struggling to use some command line parameters which I am passing in R Script. My script file looks as below:

```
library(dplyr)
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

grpd_by_variable<-get(args[1])%>%
  group_by(args[2])%>%
  mutate(DAY_GRPD_TOTAL=n())%>%
  filter(row_number()==1)

print(nrow(grpd_by_variable))
```

My command line statement is as below:

```
RScript filename.R my_data_frame col1
```

Here `my_data_frame` is the data frame I want to work on and then perform some grouping using dplyr package. `col1` is the name of the column within my data frame. When I run this command line statement, the print statement gives only 1 as output which means only one row is present. However, when I substitute the variables myself and run the script as below, it prints a value of 7, corresponding to seven days of the week.

```
grpd_by_variable<-get(my_data_frame)%>%
  group_by(col1)%>%
  mutate(DAY_GRPD_TOTAL=n())%>%
  filter(row_number()==1)

print(nrow(grpd_by_variable))
```

I believe its do with group_by(args[2[) where its not able to understand args[2] properly. Can anyone please let me know how to refer data frame's column names in the script, which are passed as command line parameters?

I have tried `group_by(args[2])`, `group_by(as.name(args[2]))`, `group_by(as.character(args[2]))` and `group_by(get(args[2]))`. But I didnt have any luck so far. As I am new to R, I couldnt figure it out exactly, but looks like its a trivial issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example:

```
#dummy arg inputs
args <- c("mtcars","gear")

#notice the "_" - "group_by_"
get(args[1]) %>% 
  group_by_(args[2]) %>% 
  mutate(cnt=n())
```

Comment: Thanks @zx8754. using group_by_ worked. Many thanks for your timely help! Marking it as an answer.